# I'm attempting to plot the square roots in a single figure. However this is not getting plotted

Tags: python, pythonplotter

I'm attempting to plot the square roots in a single figure. However, this is not getting plotted. Can somebody help me?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
for i in np.arange(1,5):
    zm=i**2        
    plt.plot(i,zm,'r')    
    print(i,zm)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

A few issues with your code:

- `zm` should be an array, but instead it is an integer that gets overwritten every cycle with the return of `i**2`,
- The `plot()` instruction should be outside the loop,
- You don't really need the for loop, you can do the square of the array with the `**` operator.

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xx = np.arange(1, 5)
zm = xx**2
plt.figure()
plt.plot(xx,zm,'r')
plt.show()
```

[image]

BTW, I believe you meant `square` and not `square root`.

I hope it helps.